# How to add clickable text link in Game Maker Studio 2?

Tags: game-maker

I was wondering if anybody knew how to add text, that when clicked, would take you to another website in Game Maker Studio 2.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new object.

Create event:

```
text = "your text";
link = "url";
font = your_font;

draw_set_font(font);
var width = string_width(text);
var height = string_height(text);

var offset = 5;
left = x - offset;
top = y - offset;
right = left + width - 1 + offset;
bottom = top + height - 1 + offset;
```

Global Mouse Left Pressed:

```
if point_in_rectangle(mouse_x, mouse_y, left, top, right, bottom)
{
    url_open(link);
}
```

Draw event:

```
draw_set_halign(fa_left);
draw_set_valign(fa_top);
draw_set_font(font);
draw_text(x, y, text);
```